# When AD denies LDAP auth, how to distinguish between different problems?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

We use corporate Active Directory as the auth-backend for various applications. Our access to AD is via LDAP.

The top three reasons for a user to fail to login are:

1. Incorrectly entered credentials
2. Expired password
3. Expired account

Is there a way to discern, from AD's response to an attempt to perform an LDAP-binding, which of the above three is the actual problem preventing a user from logging in?

Thank you!

Comment: Of course there is. You get an error code or an exception, depending on which API you use.

Answer (score 1):

You should get back an error code from which you can determine the issue. Should be a subcode of code 49, there is a list at the url below:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/474abb8f-cfc6-4cac-af79-c3e80e80291f/ldap-authentication-error-ldap-error-code-49-80090308-ldaperr-dsid0c090334-comment?forum=winserverDS